# css float for lists no working in <IE7

Tags: css, css-float

This is the HTML:

```
<nav class="listfirst"> 
    <li class="header"></li> 
    <li><a href="#"></li> 
    <li><a href="#"></li> 
    <li><a href="#"></li> 
    <li><a href="#"></li> 
    <li><a href="#"></li> 
</nav>
```

and the CSS:

```
#bottomnav{
    width:1000px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:10px;
}

#bottomnav .list1{
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
}


#bottomnav .listfirst{
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:22px;
}

#bottomnav li{
    width:165px;
    height:22px;
    margin-left:10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:block;
}
```

The lists in IE7 are just displaying as blocks and overflowing the container, whereas i need them to float left to stay in the bottomnav container.

I know it is probably a simple css fix but does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please put the related html into your question too and try to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.net (or something similar).

Comment: Can you supply the relevant HTML?

Comment: Also, you mention in the title `<IE7` that means lower than IE7, but then in the question you mention IE7? you would like <=IE7 or not?

Comment: just add code in jsfiddle that will help us

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css code.

```
  #bottomnav .list1{
     float:left;
     margin-right:20px;
     *float:left;  // this property apply in IE7
   }
```

Comment: have you tried that? the "star" rule here is doing nothing more than the normal `float` rule...

Comment: That is stupid advice. For IE7 (and 6), that just comes down to a double declaration.

Comment: @FrankConijn That is a rather harsh comment - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette. I think "incorrect" is a better choice of word here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your html is incorrect. Always need to put `<li>` between an `<ul>` tag, and perhaps you missed to close `<a>` tags?

Example:

```
<nav class="listfirst">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify:

```
#bottomnav li { 
    float:left;
}
```

cheers